# Rails 7 Import Map. Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'vega-loader' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vega-lite, vega, import-maps

I'm using Rails 7 import map feature to build a chart.
This is what I did.

```bash
 ./bin/importmap pin vega@5
 ./bin/importmap pin vega-lite@5
 ./bin/importmap pin vega-embed@6
```

And in the browser, I can see this `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'vega-loader' does not provide an export named 'default'` error on the console.

This is the similar code from the https://generator.jspm.io/ sandbox.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <!--
    JSPM Generator Import Map
    Edit URL: https://generator.jspm.io/#U2VhYGBmD80rySzJSU1hKEtNT9RNzU1KTXEw0zMy1DOAiORklqQ6mOqZQflAppGRniEAk3dJ3DwA
  -->
  <script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vega": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega@5.22.1/build/vega.module.js",
      "vega-embed": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-embed@6.21.0/build/vega-embed.module.js",
      "vega-lite": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-lite@5.6.0/build/src/index.js"
    },
    "scopes": {
      "https://ga.jspm.io/": {
        "buffer": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@jspm/core@2.0.0-beta.27/nodelibs/browser/buffer.js",
        "clone": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:clone@2.1.2/clone.js",
        "d3-array": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-array@3.1.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-color": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-color@3.1.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-delaunay": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-delaunay@6.0.2/src/index.js",
        "d3-dispatch": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-dispatch@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-dsv": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-dsv@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-force": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-force@3.0.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-format": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-format@3.1.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-geo": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-geo@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-geo-projection": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-geo-projection@4.0.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-hierarchy": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-hierarchy@3.1.2/src/index.js",
        "d3-interpolate": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-interpolate@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-path": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-path@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-quadtree": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-quadtree@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "d3-scale": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-scale@4.0.2/src/index.js",
        "d3-shape": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-shape@3.1.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-time": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-time@3.0.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-time-format": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-time-format@4.1.0/src/index.js",
        "d3-timer": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-timer@3.0.1/src/index.js",
        "delaunator": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:delaunator@5.0.0/index.js",
        "fast-deep-equal": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:fast-deep-equal@3.1.3/index.js",
        "fast-json-patch": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:fast-json-patch@3.1.1/index.mjs",
        "fast-json-stable-stringify": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:fast-json-stable-stringify@2.1.0/index.js",
        "internmap": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:internmap@2.0.3/src/index.js",
        "json-stringify-pretty-compact": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:json-stringify-pretty-compact@3.0.0/index.js",
        "robust-predicates": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:robust-predicates@3.0.1/index.js",
        "topojson-client": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:topojson-client@3.1.0/dist/topojson-client.js",
        "vega-canvas": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-canvas@1.2.6/build/vega-canvas.min.js",
        "vega-crossfilter": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-crossfilter@4.1.0/build/vega-crossfilter.module.js",
        "vega-dataflow": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-dataflow@5.7.4/build/vega-dataflow.js",
        "vega-encode": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-encode@4.9.0/build/vega-encode.module.js",
        "vega-event-selector": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-event-selector@3.0.0/build/vega-event-selector.module.js",
        "vega-expression": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-expression@5.0.0/build/vega-expression.module.js",
        "vega-force": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-force@4.1.0/build/vega-force.module.js",
        "vega-format": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-format@1.1.0/build/vega-format.module.js",
        "vega-functions": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-functions@5.13.0/build/vega-functions.module.js",
        "vega-geo": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-geo@4.4.0/build/vega-geo.module.js",
        "vega-hierarchy": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-hierarchy@4.1.0/build/vega-hierarchy.module.js",
        "vega-interpreter": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-interpreter@1.0.4/build/vega-interpreter.js",
        "vega-label": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-label@1.2.0/build/vega-label.module.js",
        "vega-loader": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-loader@4.5.0/build/vega-loader.browser.module.js",
        "vega-parser": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-parser@6.1.4/build/vega-parser.module.js",
        "vega-projection": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-projection@1.5.0/build/vega-projection.module.js",
        "vega-regression": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-regression@1.1.0/build/vega-regression.module.js",
        "vega-runtime": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-runtime@6.1.3/build/vega-runtime.js",
        "vega-scale": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-scale@7.2.0/build/vega-scale.module.js",
        "vega-scenegraph": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-scenegraph@4.10.1/build/vega-scenegraph.module.js",
        "vega-schema-url-parser": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-schema-url-parser@2.2.0/dist/parser.js",
        "vega-selections": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-selections@5.4.0/build/vega-selection.module.js",
        "vega-statistics": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-statistics@1.8.0/build/vega-statistics.module.js",
        "vega-themes": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-themes@2.12.0/build/vega-themes.module.js",
        "vega-time": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-time@2.1.0/build/vega-time.module.js",
        "vega-tooltip": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-tooltip@0.28.0/build/vega-tooltip.module.js",
        "vega-transforms": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-transforms@4.10.0/build/vega-transforms.module.js",
        "vega-util": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-util@1.17.0/build/vega-util.module.js",
        "vega-view": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-view@5.11.0/build/vega-view.module.js",
        "vega-view-transforms": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-view-transforms@4.5.8/build/vega-view-transforms.js",
        "vega-voronoi": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-voronoi@4.2.0/build/vega-voronoi.module.js",
        "vega-wordcloud": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega-wordcloud@4.1.3/build/vega-wordcloud.js"
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <!-- ES Module Shims: Import maps polyfill for modules browsers without import maps support (all except Chrome 89+) -->
  <script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.5.1/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script type="module">
    import * as vega from "vega";
    import * as vegaEmbed from "vega-embed";
    import * as vegaLite from "vega-lite";
  
    // Write main module code here, or as a separate file with a "src" attribute on the module script.
    console.log(vega, vegaEmbed, vegaLite);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was likely a module export style difference that has since been corrected upstream.

I'm able to reproduce the issue with the posted html, but **re-running the imports** with a new Rails 7 app nets **newer versions of vega and d3** that don't report an error.

e.g. at this time rails imports:

```
pin "vega", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:vega@5.24.0/build/vega.module.js"
pin "d3-array", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-array@3.2.3/src/index.js"
pin "d3-color", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:d3-color@3.1.0/src/index.js"
```

You might try unpinning and pinning again:

```bash
 ./bin/importmap unpin vega@5
 ./bin/importmap unpin vega-lite@5
 ./bin/importmap unpin vega-embed@6

 ./bin/importmap pin vega@5
 ./bin/importmap pin vega-lite@5
 ./bin/importmap pin vega-embed@6
```

Can't say for certain but I'd guess that vega 5.23.0 is what fixed this.  Looks like they jumped from rollup 2.70.1 to 3.17.3 (fairly substantial).